# word-break: break-word not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, flexbox

I am using flexbox and trying to handle long strings that don't have spaces. The variable `word-break: break-word` is ideal for me because it breaks only long words unlike `word-break: break-all` that brakes also short words instead of dropping them to the next line.

My problem is that it works only in Chrome. Is there a way to get working also in IE / FIREFOX **(With flexbox)** ?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqLmoO

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 33vw;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.item_brake_all {
  display: flex;
  width: 33vw;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<p align=center><b><u>Can I get the two top DIVS to display correctly in IE / FIREFOX?</b></u>

  <p align=center>In this div the word should brake:
    <div class="page">


      <div class="content">
        <div class="item">DavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavid</div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <p align=center>In this div no word should brake:
      <div class="page">


        <div class="content">
          <div class="item">In this div the words should not brake because all the words are small. If a specific reaches the end of the container and has no room it should just fall to next line. With 'brake-all' the browser will brake the word like in the example below.</div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <p align=center><b>Example why I dont want to use brake-all:</b>
        <div class="page">


          <div class="content">
            <div class="item_brake_all">In this div the words should not brake because all the words are small. If a specific reaches the end of the container and has no room it should just fall to next line. With 'brake-all' the browser will brake the word.</div>

          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I do believe you don't need `display: flex` in `.item`, the following will work across browsers:

```
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 33vw;
  word-break: break-word; /* Chrome, Safari */
  word-wrap: break-word; /* IE11, Firefox */
}
```

**Why does this work?**

It would be naive to simply say that `flex-direction: column` forces the flex block to respect the element's width. The explanation is far more complicated, I hope some CSS guru could shed some light on this one.

Comment: Impressive! Worked indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason you need `display: flex` in `.item`? If not, then `word-wrap: break-word` will do the same thing in IE/FF:

```
.item {
  /* display:flex; */
  width: 33vw;
  /*   word-break: break-word; */
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: This is in-fact an accurate answer. But I need the solution in FlexBox....

Comment: @DavidSomekh It is in Flexbox...the `item` is a flex item

Comment: What I mean is that I can keep using display:flex

Comment: Why do you need `display: flex` in `.item`? What do you expect it to do?